# Two way comparison in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have just started my journey with Pandas Library. Actually I was trying to explore the [Kaggle | Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic).

So, there is actually a column called "Fare".

I want to find out who has "Fare" == 0

I can do it using,

```
print titanic_df[titanic_df["Fare"] == 0] #titanic_df is my DataFrame
```

and I fully understand the process.

Now I saw someone saying an use of 2 way comparison on the Pandas DataFrame and is given by

```
print titanic_df["Fare"][titanic_df["Fare"] == 0]
```

This also got the same number of rows printed. I'm quite confused as to how the code is executed (what is he meaning of the second index). I might be asking a very stupid question, but I searched a lot before this, without any success.

Please bear with me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the output is the same? The first one is supposed to give you a *DataFrame* where the condition is met. The second one just gives you the `Fare`  column where `Fare == 0`

Comment: The outputs aren't the same.

Comment: @ayhan, Sorry! Not the same. You are correct.

Comment: @ayhan, is the interpretation is like this - I can go on adding condition as indexes?

Comment: It's called boolean indexing. `titanic_df["Fare"] == 0`  returns a boolean array. If you pass this to a DataFrame, it will give you the corresponding rows where the values in the array are `True`. So you get the whole DataFrame with those rows. If you pass this to a Series (`df['Fare']` for example)  it will give you the corresponding elements for that Series.

Comment: @ayhan. Thanks! Just one more thing, I can create a boolean array by ANDing 2 boolean arrays with 2 conditions? And if I pass them the same manner, I will get results of the ANDed comparison?

Comment: Yes, you can combine two conditions with `&`  operator. `df[(df['x'] > 0) & (df['y'] < 0)]`  for example. The parenthesis are important because `&`  has a higher precedence. The docs have detailed explanations and examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between those two types of selections is that the first returns 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' and the second returns 'pandas.core.series.Series'

```
print type(titanic_train_df[titanic_train_df["Fare"] == 0])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Which is all of the columns for the selected rows, where 'Fare' == 0.

```
print type(titanic_train_df["Fare"][titanic_train_df["Fare"] == 0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Which is only the 'Fare' column of the selected rows, where 'Fare' == 0.